# How to return Table in Multi-Statement Table valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions, sql-function

So I have Multi-Statement Table valued function has input and output parameters like this

```
    CREATE FUNCTION fn_SearchByText 
(
    @AdTitle varchar(100)
)
RETURNS @output TABLE(AdID varchar(20), AdTitle varchar(50), BrandName varchar(20), 
ModelName varchar(20), ModelType varchar(20), ModelYear int, Describe varchar(350),
Price int, PostedDate datetime
)
```

And after few lines of code I have statement as mentioned below
PS:@like is a declared variable in from the code

```
SET @query ='select AdID, AdTitle, BrandName, ModelName, ModelType, ModelYear,
    Describe, Price, PostedDate from Ads where AdTitle is not null '+ @like;
    exec sp_executesql @query;
```

So How can I return table from the last statement.

Please help

Comment: Insert that data into the return table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but you can't execute a dynamic SQL from inside a TVF. Make it a stored procedure, it will allow for this (although not so elegantly).

Comment: Thanks will use a Store procedure instead of TVP